# AndroidJunit4.class runner in Android Studio does not invoke @Test methods

Tags: android, android-studio, junit4

I have applied the following instructions: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide
to setup JUnit4 tests.

In particular I am following the steps to use Junit4 with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 however when I run tests in Android Studio the @Test annotated methods are not being executed. If I prefix methods with 'test' it works however this is not what I expect for the JUnit 4 tests.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Regards,

Comment: Did you add the `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` annotation to the class? See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v6.4/Testing/JUnit4/src/androidTest/java/com/commonsware/android/abf/test/DemoActivityTest.java

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I have that annotation as per the wiki and I also have the runner in my graddle build 'testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"'. Unfortunatley still not picking up the methods. (If my class does not extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 then it works however I need to extend this to get access to the Android SDK api)

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` anymore. If you need access to an `Activity`, in the test support libraries `ActivityTestRule` exists. Instead of extending `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` you can now do:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public final class ActivityTest {

    @Rule 
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void useActivityInTest() {
        Activity activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke I moved to the new testing support in AS (unit tests and instrumentaton tests) and in the process moved to using rules and all lis good.

Comment: Confirmed by the last examples released and presented [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/NPagF6bpHsv)

Answer (score 2):

I found I had to add a single test method like this:

```
public void test() {}
```

Then all of my real tests are annotated with `@Test`

Comment: Thanks ericharlow, I found that adding a null test like this ironically did make it work (hence I am +1 your answer), however I was not happy with this and since then I have decided to move AS 1.2.2 with Android Plugin Version: 1.2.3 and this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed when specified in the file *app/build.gradle* the test-runner:

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.domain.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to run an individual test method in Android Studio (by right clicking and selecting it from the context menu) rather than the whole class.

Running the whole class caused the test to run as expected.